# Http 404 spring mvc

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, http-status-code-404

i am not able to figure out how to solve 404 error in running an spring mvc application .

can some one please guide me how to avoid 404 error in general for spring mvc application without using annotation configuration rather xml configuaration .

Please also let me know of working war file or zip which i can import in eclipse for spring mvc directly and learn about the components .

Thanks 
Prakaash

Comment: Make sure you are in the correct url that the server assigns to you (tomcat or whatever server you are using) e.g. localhost:8888/myapp.
You can try starting with the "getting started" projects of spring, that can be automatically imported with the spring tool suite plug-in for eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP 404 mean that the requested resource (url) is not found.

In most cases either:

- Your Application is not really started
- Your Application is mapped to an complete different url than you expected
- There is no handler for the requested url in the application

So in general: 404 is not a error by itself, in the most cases it is a bug in your application or in your understanding of how it works.

But you will not get an better answer, as long as you do not post more details about your application, as well as the URL you try to invoke.